# MySQL: fill table column from other column with pivot table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, "questions", "q_t" -> pivot table and "tags":

I need to fill tags.lid with first occurrence in q_t.tid to be = questions.lid

"questions" table structure:

```
qid     lid
1       901
2       901
3       500
4       500
5       200
6       210
7       333
8       423
```

"q_t" table structure:

```
qid    tid
1       8
2       4
3       8
4       1
1       2
6       3
2       8
8       1
```

"tags" table structure:

```
tid     lid
1       null
2       null
3       null
4       null
5       null
6       null
7       null
8       null
```

I need "tags" table to be:

```
tid     lid
1       500
2       901
3       210
4       901
5       null
6       null
7       null
8       901
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a query like this:

```
UPDATE tags t
SET t.lid = (
  SELECT q.lid
  FROM questions q
  JOIN q_t ON (q.qid = q_t.qid)
  WHERE q_t.tid = t.tid
  LIMIT 1
)
```

It might not be the best performance-wise, but for a one-time job, it should do.

As an alternative:

```
UPDATE tags t
JOIN (
  SELECT q.lid, q_t.tid
  FROM questions q
  JOIN q_t USING (qid)
  GROUP BY q_t.tid
) d USING(tid)
SET t.lid = d.lid
```